# How to load JS file before loading the DOM completely?

Tags: javascript

I am using *sweetAlert* for javascript validations. I loaded the JS for *sweetAlert* in my controller's constructor.

Based on condition in auth function of controller I need to display a swal('Hello World); to user. But when it comes to auth function , it console me below error :

> Uncaught (in promise) SweetAlert: You can only use SweetAlert AFTER
> the DOM has loaded!

Below I am providing some lines of code where I am using swal function.

#### Controller

```
function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('CommonModel');
    $this->load->model('UserModel');
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js" language="javascript" ></script>
    <?
    $this->load->library(array('session', 'form_validation', 'pagination'));
}
```

#### Below is the auth function where I am using swal

```
else{
   echo "<script type='text/javascript'>swal('Hello world!');</script>";
}
```

Please help me in this

Comment: Asking the wrong question. Should be *"how do i implement this after the dom is loaded"*

Comment: I think your `echo` string isn't called at the right moment. when is it called? this is difficult to answer since we do not know how the rest of the code is structured.

Comment: The documentation for [SweetAlert](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/) very clearly says multiple times "make sure it's called after the DOM has loaded!".  It's not really clear from the code you provided here how to fix that, however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
else{
   echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
        swal('Hello world!');
      });
</script>";
}
```

This ensures that dom is loaded.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Mohit.. It helped me partially , now I can see swal but I want to redirect the user to another function only when user click on Ok. After your answer My code looks like below:
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>
              document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
swal('Hello world!');window.open('index#perfectMatch','_self');
});
</script>";
Please guide me for this